# Printing number from a range without using any number in program

Tags: python-3.x

We have to print a range of numbers without using any numeric in the program.
I have made a program that is correctly working but i need to optimize it more.
This is a program made by me in python:

```
for x in range(ord('F'),ord('Q')):
    print(x)
```

Comment: Lose the `x = ord('F')` and `x += ord('G')-ord('F')` lines as they are not doing anything.

Comment: are you looking fro something like `[x for x in range(ord("F"),ord('Q'))]`??

Comment: It would be lot better if you indented the program properly, people can get easily confused to think it's a list comprehension without the square brackets.